# Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type - Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am new to typescript, I am trying to learn how to use Json Web Token to authenticate a typescript API but I am getting this error whenever I do npm start.

Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type.

```
19 app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
                    ~~~
```

Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.

```
19 app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
```

This is my code, it is just a simple authentication with JWT

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: 'Welcome to the API'
  });
});

app.post('/api/posts', verifyToken, (req, res) => {  
  jwt.verify(req.token, 'secretkey', (err, authData) => {
    if(err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {
      res.json({
        message: 'Post created...',
        authData
      });
    }
  });
});

app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
  // Mock user
  const user = {
    id: 1, 
    username: 'brad',
    email: 'brad@gmail.com'
  }

  jwt.sign({user}, 'secretkey', (err, token) => {
    res.json({
      token
    });
  });
});


function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
  if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];
    req.token = bearerToken;
    next();
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
}
```

how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using express:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
app.get('/api', (req: Request, res: Response) => {..}
```

You can be general and write the code as: (not advised)

```
app.get('/api', (req: any, res: any) => {..}
```

Comment: The types should be inferred automatically. If they are not it indicates that configuration problem or missing package. Explicit annotation of inline callback parameters can hide errors, increases coupling, and is verbose.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the type of the parameter just after it.

```
app.get('/api', (req:any, res:any) => {
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30662680)